# Improper integral of odd function

Tags: probability, improper-integrals, symmetric-functions

I'm a student. In a recent assignment I was asked to find the mean of a Student's t multivariate distribution (which should be $\overline\mu$).

I've divided the integral required to find the expected value into two pieces, and one of the two,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\overline{z}\frac{1}{[1+\dfrac{1}{v}\overline{z}^T\mathbf\Sigma^{-1}\overline{z}]^\frac{v+p}{2}}d\overline{z}{}{}$$

is supposed to be zero. However since this is an improper integral I can't get away with saying that, due to the odd property of the integrated function, the result is $0$ (an obvious example is $1/x$). Do I need to work out the whole thing or is there a way to prove that odd functions with no singularities actually do integrate to $0$ over improper integrals.

I looked around but I couldn't find any mention about it, though in one of my books they reduce a similar integral to zero without explaining, hence my question.

Comment: What is $T$, and what is $\Sigma^{-1}$? It could be done by comparison...

Comment: Since the distribution is multivariate, z is a vector and $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix. I use T to indicate the transpose. I have fixed the question to reflect this.